# Rigid \'etale cohohomology of flag variety minus its rational points e.g $p$-adic Drinfeld half plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, etale-cohomology, rigid-analytic-geometry

Let $Fl=G/B$ over $\mathbb Q_p$ be the flag variety of a quasi-split reductive group $G$ over $\mathbb Q_p$, then $X=Fl-Fl(Q_p)$ shall exist as a rigid analytic variety over $\mathbb Q_p$, how to compute $H^*_c(X_{\mathbb C_p}, \mathbb Q_\ell)$ (as a $G(\mathbb Q_p) \times Gal_{\mathbb Q_p}$ representation)?

Motivation: Drinfeld half plane, I don't know any mordern reference for such computation (some related things can be found in "Survey on Drinfeld modules").

The real number analogue shall be easier.

Comment: This particular case can be easily handled using excision, relating it to the cohomology of the flag variety, and the $H^0$ on $\mathrm{Fl}(\mathbb Q_p)$, which will just contribute an induced representation. For the closely related $p$-adic period domains, there's recently a lot of work on such computations with $p$-adic coefficients (which are harder, but often give reminders on the $\ell$-adic case), see for example the series of works of Colmez--Dospinescu--Niziol.